# I have an article "state" managed by a boolean field, but how can I get the first date (timestamp) when the checkbox was saved as published?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, timestamp

I hope this isn't just a friday brainfart, but here are more details:

I have an article model that only shows to the public when each article is marked as "published" and saved. However, the only timestamp is on create or update, so if someone creates an article on Monday, but publishes Friday, it will still show up as created Monday (thus not at the top of the feed).

Can provide code if needed, but if anyone has a quick thought that would be great. Please ask what code you need to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would convert the `boolean` column `published` to `timestamp`.
Set it to `now()` when published, leave it `NULL` until published.

Comment: Good stuff Erwin. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

If publishing the article was the last update you can sort by the `updated_at` column.